# How to auto fill textbox from database when user type some characters in MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a text box in my _layout page where user type some characters
and when user is typing it should check for like condition and its should be able to show the suggestions from the database.

i have created a

```
public JsonResult AutoCompleteCountry(string term)
{
    var result = (from r in db.CountryMaster
                  where r.Country_Name.ToLower().Contains(term.ToLower())
                  select new { r.Country_Name}).Distinct();
    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

but i am not able to use the jquery as browser is showing **jQuery** is not defined, and even i am not able to use datapicker for the same so please provide help have installed jquery UI library in my project

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#Country").autocomplete({
            source: function(request,response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Visa/AutoCompleteCountry",
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: { term: request.term },
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data, function (item) {
                            return { label: item.Country, value: item.Country };
                        }))

                    }
                })
            },
            messages: {
                noResults: "", results: ""
            }
        });
    })
    </script>

_layout @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery") @Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css") 

in BundleConfig.cs bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include( "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js", "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js"));
```

bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/themes/base/css").Include( "~/Content/themes/base/core.css", "~/Content/themes/base/resizable.css", "~/Content/themes/base/selectable.css", "~/Content/themes/base/accordion.css", "~/Content/themes/base/autocomplete.css")); and so on

@using (Html.BeginForm("Global", "Visa", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "navbar-form navbar-left", role = "search" }))
               {

```
               {
                <div class="form-group">

                    <input type="text" id="Country" data-provide="typehead" class="form-control" placeholder="Type Country Name" autocomplete="on" name="C">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default glyphicon glyphicon-search"></button>
            }
           }
```

Comment: There is a problem with the code in your view but you have not even shown it! _Query is not defined_ means just that - you have not included the jquery script in your view

Comment: No stephen this was not the case

Comment: OP has asking the way how he can make Autocomplete

Comment: @Dilip, Read the question - _"but i am not able to use the jquery as browser is showing jQuery is not defined"_ The code OP has shown has nothing to do with the issue (that works just fine).

Comment: "How to auto fill textbox from database when user type some characters in MVC 5 ""

This is initial title i think

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108819/discussion-between-dilip-and-stephen-muecke).

Comment: Please show how you are referencing jquery and jquery ui. It's either you did not referenced jquery correctly or you did not referenced it at all.

Comment: Thnak You for the reply

Comment: this code in my _layout    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css")

Comment: in BundleConfig.cs  bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(  
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js"));

Comment: bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/themes/base/css").Include(  
                        "~/Content/themes/base/core.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/resizable.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/selectable.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/accordion.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/autocomplete.css",
                        and so on

Comment: @dilip  and stephen Muecke i have bot the issue as i have just started using MVC as i have no web development exp was completely on desktop dev

Comment: and even i am not able to use datepicker as only a textbox appear on the page